# Create custom numeric-only keypad within comma decimal separator

Tags: android, jquery, html, ios

I need to present a numeric keyboard (no alpha chars at all) to the user when the focus is in a text field inside a webview, the keyboard should have *comma* as decimal separator. 
I tried to show a custom keyboard in Safari mobile in this example:

[image: Form with a custom numeric keyboard]

It would be perfect if the *comma* would be present inside a keyboard like this.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)! You need to try to write the code **yourself**. After doing [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and you still have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of **what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: @SankarshMakam I hope it's more clear now. Thanks for your suggestion.